# grouping by time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this query:

```
   SELECT *  FROM `mfw_navnode` n1
    WHERE  (n1.node_name='Eby' OR n1.node_name='Lana'  OR n1.node_name='MF' OR n1.node_name='Amur' OR n1.node_name='Asin' )
    GROUP BY n1.node_name
```

It has another field which is called time_added..that is basically the time of each row..I want to order the node_name (Select them), by the latest time I added them.

How do I do it? each node_name has a time.. but I want to group each node_name by the latest time it was added..

I thought to use MAX(time_added) and then add it to group by..but that gave me an error..

What could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, the following may be what you are looking for.  It isn't quite clear to me if you want them ordered with the latest times first or last (add `DESC` as needed):

```
SELECT `node_name`,  max(`time`) `maxtime` FROM `mfw_navnode` n1 ...
        GROUP BY node_name order by `maxtime`;
```

One thing to note is that the query in the OP, which includes fields not in the GROUP BY clause is ambiguous and is not allowed in most SQL implementations.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd:  It means "order by the second item in the select list".  It's just a shortcut (and probably a bad one because if you change the order of the items in the select clause but forget to update that, then you have an error).  I'll edit it and appropriately alias it.

Comment: would it matter if I ordered by time..without the max feature...and do order desc

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd:  Well ... it would produce a different result.  And, again, if you don't use the aggregate `max` then you need to include the time field in the GROUP BY to avoid an ambiguous result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  FROM `mfw_navnode` n1
WHERE  (n1.node_name='Eby' OR n1.node_name='Lana'  OR n1.node_name='MF' OR n1.node_name='Amur' OR n1.node_name='Asin' )
GROUP BY n1.node_name
ORDER BY n1.time_added DESC
```

Order by DESC automatically shows most recently created first.

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, n1.node_name ORDER BY n1.time_added DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

Comment: It should be `GROUP BY n1.node_name` and not `GROUP BY DESC, n1.node_name` - `GROU BY DESC` is a copy mistake I guess...